# Windows Explorer's right click context menu call

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way to open Explorer's file-right-click context menu in c# and perform clicked action?
I suppose it is just file's path that is supplied to that context menu items.

Comment: Yes, but not easily.  You need lots of P/Invoke.

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack may help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a namespace extension: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/04/01/WindowsShell/default.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20060828124151/http://msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmag/issues/04/01/WindowsShell/default.aspx)